# Find the next prime number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that takes a number (for example, 5) and returns the first prime number after the input number (in this case, it would be 7).

This is my code:

```
def prime(n):
    np=[]
    isprime=[]
    for i in range (n+1,n+200):
        np.append(i)
    for x in range(2,199):
        for j in np:
            if x%j!=0:
                isprime.append(x)
    return min(isprime)
```

However, this code doesn't work (it always returns 2). Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 3):

You have a few mistakes, most notably `np` is clearly meant to be the potential primes (it starts at `n+1` which is the first potential number that fits your critera *"the first prime number after the input number"*), and yet you add `x` to your prime list, which is from `range(2,199)`, you should be using:

```
isprime.append(j)
```

Your primality test is also the wrong way round as a result, you should be using:

```
j % x != 0
```

Lastly, you can't append a number if that condition is true in one case, it has to be true in *all* cases (where x is an integer which satisfies `2 <= x < j`), because of this you should switch your second set of for loops around (the `x` loop should be the inner loop), and you should also only loop up to `j-1` (the number being tested). Additionally, you should instead choose to *not* add an item if `j % x == 0`:

```
for ...:
    val_is_prime = True
    for ...:
        if j % x == 0:
            val_is_prime = False
            break
    if val_is_prime:
        isprime.append(j)
```

This results in the following code:

```
def prime(n):
    np=[]
    isprime=[]
    for i in range (n+1,n+200):
        np.append(i)
    for j in np:
        val_is_prime = True
        for x in range(2,j-1):
            if j % x == 0:
                val_is_prime = False
                break
        if val_is_prime:
            isprime.append(j)
    return min(isprime)
```

And test run:

```
>>> prime(5)
7
>>> prime(13)
17
>>> prime(23)
29
```

---

Note that there's several other efficiency improvements that could be made, but this answer focuses on the mistakes rather than improvements

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, the most pythonic and clear way to do this that I found (but probably not the most efficient):

```
def is_prime(x):
    return all(x % i for i in range(2, x))

def next_prime(x):
    return min([a for a in range(x+1, 2*x) if is_prime(a)])

print(next_prime(9))
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-simpy-nextprime-method/

```
from sympy import *
  
# calling nextprime function on differnet numbers 
nextprime(7) 
nextprime(13) 
nextprime(2)
```

> Output:
>
> 11 17 3

Answer (score 1):

This code working.

```
def prime(n):
    next_prime = n + 1
    prime = True
    while True:
        for i in range(2, next_prime):
            if next_prime%i ==0:
                prime = False
                break
        if prime:
            return next_prime
        else:
            next_prime = next_prime + 1
            if next_prime % 2 == 0:
                next_prime = next_prime + 1
            prime = True


if __name__=="__main__":
    print(prime(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one working sample.

```
inputNumber = int(input("Enter number to find next prime: "))

def nextPrime(inputNum):

    for nextNumToChk in range(inputNum+1, inputNum +200):
        if nextNumToChk > 1:
            # If num is divisible by any number between 2 and val, it is not prime
            for i in range(2, nextNumToChk):
                if (nextNumToChk % i) == 0:
                    break
            else:
                #found the prime
                return nextNumToChk

result = nextPrime(inputNumber)
print "Next Prime is : ",result
```

Output:-

```
Enter number to find next prime: 5
Next Prime is :  7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime(n):
    # Corner case
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    # Check from 2 to n-1
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def first_prime_over(n):
    prime_number = (i for i in range(n) if is_prime(i))
    try:
        for i in range(0,n):
            (next(prime_number))
    except StopIteration:
        prime_number_next = (i for i in range(n,n+1000) if is_prime(i))
        print(next(prime_number_next))
first_prime_over(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
def find_next_prime(n):
    return find_prime_in_range(n, 2*n)

def find_prime_in_range(a, b):
    for c in range(a, b):
        for i in range(2, c):
            if c % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            return c
    return None

def main():
    n = int(input('Find the next prime number from: '))
    print(find_next_prime(n+1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("Enter a number"))

while True:
    n+=1
    for  x in range(2,n):
        if n%x==0:
           break
    else:
         print("next prime number is",n)
         break
```