# I can't get these values to work in Python

Tags: python

I need to enter 2 values and then make basic mathematical operations and then print them out.

This is what I have so far:

```
def next_multiple(number, k):
    number = input("zadej hodnotu - num")
    k = input("zadej hodnotu - k")
    poc=0
    for _ in iter(int, 1):poc=number + 1
    if (poc % k ==0): break
    
print ("Tohle prošlo")

def next_prime(number):
    pass


def main():
    assert next_multiple(1, 2) == 2
    assert next_multiple(10, 7) == 14
    assert next_multiple(10, 5) == 15
    assert next_multiple(54, 6) == 60
    assert next_multiple(131, 29) == 145
    assert next_multiple(123, 112) == 224
    assert next_multiple(423, 90) == 450

    assert next_prime(1) == 2
    assert next_prime(2) == 3
    assert next_prime(3) == 5
    assert next_prime(4) == 5
    assert next_prime(11) == 13
    assert next_prime(12) == 13


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: what's not working?

Comment: You need to convert the input to an integer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you give us some more details about the exact errors that you are getting? What would be the expected behavior?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `iter(int, 1)`?

Comment: `break` can only be used inside a loop. Your `if` statement isn't in the `for` loop.

Comment: Why does your function ask for input at all? It gets the values from the function parameters.

Comment: There's no need for a loop. If `number % k == 0` the answer is `number + k`. Otherwise it's `(number // k + 1) * k`

Comment: Isn't the next_multiple function supposed to return something?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a chaos with multiple implementations in your code :) Your code should look something like this:

```py
def next_multiple(number, k):
    return (number+ (k-(number%k) if number%k!=0 else 0))
    
def main():
    assert next_multiple(1, 2) == 2
    assert next_multiple(10, 7) == 14
   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Since you are expecting a return value from the function, you should return a value. Also if you want to exclude number input, for example if you want next_multiple(24,4) to return 28, do as follows:

```py
return (number+ k-(number%k))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue with the **next_multiple** are:

- Your function requires two parameters (number, k), but then you ask for them with the input function, you cant set a condition of both **number** and **k** if they do not given to the function.
- input: return a string, not at integer, therefore you need to use **int()** to change the type of the variable to an int.
- If and break out of for.
- Your function doesn't return any value, use **return**

Code with corrections:

```
def next_multiple(number = None, k = None):
    if not number:
        number = int(input("zadej hodnotu - num"))
    if not k:
        k = int(input("zadej hodnotu - k"))
    poc=0
    for _ in iter(int, 1):
        poc=number + 1
        if (poc % k ==0):
            break
    return poc
```

For the 2nd function: you can use any of these solutions.

[Find the next prime number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003330/find-the-next-prime-number-in-python)