# Next Prime Number in Python

Tags: python, primes

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm practicing to code this problem I saw. Next prime is needed, but there are limitations on the input. I have searched for similar questions, but my code is still not working. Hope you can help. Thank you!

The problem I get is when I enter 32, the results show 33 when the next prime is 37...

Here's my code so far.

```
num = int(input("Enter a positive number:"))   

import math

def nextprime(n):
    if n < 0:
      raise ValueError
  
    for next in range(n + 1, n +200):
        if next > 1:
            for i in range(2, next):
                if (next % i) == 0:
                    break
                else:
                    return next
```

Comment: What steps did you take to debug your problem? You will find the problem with the most basic step-in debug process. on the first iteration of the outer loop, `next` is `33`. On the first iteration of the inner loop, `i` is `2`. Since 33 is not divisible by 2 - you return it...

Comment: Your prime test loop makes no sense.  If a number divides the candidate, it just continues, so clearly it's not going to reject anything that way.  But if a number doesn't divide the candidate, then it immediately returns the candidate, so clearly it's going to find non-primes.  It needs to do this:  If a number divides the candidate, it needs to immediately *reject* the candidate, exit the inner loop, and continue on to the next candidate in the outer loop.  If it makes it to the end of the inner loop with no factors being found, *then* it returns the candidate, which must be prime.

Comment: You need to try to reason it out.  Run some examples.  Figure out an algorithm that will actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code when you arrive to a number that reminder is not zero you return that number. You need a flag for every number this flag is True if can be divide flag convert to False for the first number that flag not convert to false return that number like below.

**Don't use `next` because this is a builtin function.**

Try this: *(I don't improve your code)*

```
def nextprime(n):
    if n < 0:
      raise ValueError
  
    for i in range(n + 1, n +200):
        if i > 1:
            pr = True
            for j in range(2, i):
                if (i % j) == 0:
                    pr = False
                    break
            if pr:
                return i
    return 'not found'
```

You can also try this code, write function to check that a number is prime or not like `def is_prime` then for number of larger that you input num find `min` number next. *(this answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64026396/1740577).)*

```
def is_prime(x):
    return all(x % i for i in range(2, x))

def next_prime(x):
    return min([a for a in range(x+1, 2*x) if is_prime(a)])

print(next_prime(32))
```

You can also use `sympy` like below: *(this answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64662152/1740577).)*

```
from sympy import *
nextprime(32)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def next_prime(n):
    while True:
        n=n+1
        for i in range (2,int(n/2)):
            if n%i==0:
                break
        else:
            return n


print(next_prime(67))
```

Comment: Please explain your code

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Few off-topic tips:

1. as user1740577 mentioned, don't use `next` as a variable name
2. refrain from using `eval` when possible, it's okay here, but in real project this will lead to big no-no.
3. Place imports at the very top of your script
4. Consider using variable names `i` and `j` only for iterations.
5. For duplicate `except` blocks use `(Error, Error)`

As for solution to your problem, with some adjustments, if you don't mind

```py
def next_prime(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError('Negative numbers can not be primes')
    # Base case
    if n <= 1:
        return 2
    
    # For i as every odd number between n + 1 and n + 200
    for i in range(n + 1 + (n % 2), n + 200, 2):
        # For every odd number from 3 to i (3 because we covered base case)
        for j in range(3, i, 2):
            # If remained is equals to 0
            if not i % j:
                # break current loop
                break
        # If loop j didn't break [nobreak: ]
        else:
            return i
    raise RuntimeError('Failed to compute next prime number :c')


def main():
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input('Enter positive number: '))
            print(f'Next prime is: {next_prime(num)}')
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a positive integer!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some speed improvements to the code from @rajendra-kumbar:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
import math

def next_prime(number):
    if number < 0:
        raise ValueError('Negative numbers can not be primes')
    # Base case
    if number <= 1:
        return 2

    # if even go back 1
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number -= 1
    while True:
        # only odds
        number += 2
        #only need to check up to and including the sqrt
        max_check = int(math.sqrt(number))+2
        # don't need to check even numbers
        for divider in range(3, max_check, 2):
            # if 'divider' divides 'number', then 'number' is not prime
            if number % divider == 0:
                break
        # if the for loop didn't break, then 'number' is prime
        else:
            return number

if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = int(sys.argv[1].strip())
    t0 = time.time()
    print('{0:d} is the next prime from {1:d}'.format(next_prime(number), number))
    run_time = time.time() - t0
    print('run_time = {0:.8f}'.format(run_time))
```

it is about twice as fast

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like simple:

```
def is_prime(number:int):
 check = 0
 for i in range(2,number):
    if number % i == 0:
        check += 1
 if check == 0:
    return True
 else:
    return False

def next_prime(value):
 check = value + 1
 while is_prime(check) is False:
    check += 1
 return check

value = int(input("Insert the number: "))
print(next_prime(value))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).